# return the value from second event under ajax result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

is this possible to achieve? I already get the value I wanted from ajax result but in second part I want THAT value to return from another event. Currently it returns 'undefined'. Please see my code below. Any idea? Thanks in advance! :)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
      $.ajax({ 
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'myURL.php', 
      data: dataString,
      success: function (data) { 
           console.log(data);
           var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
           if(!$.isEmptyObject(obj))
           {
                $.each(obj, function(index, record) {
                    $('#updateRecord').append('<input type="text" id="regionDesc" value="' + record.firstValue + '"><button type="submit" id="submit" data-theme="b">Update</button>'); 
                });
           }

           $("#update").click(function() {
            var regionDesc= $("regionDesc").val();
            console.log(regionDesc);
       });
     });
 });
```

SOLUTION :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
      $.ajax({ 
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'myURL.php', 
      data: dataString,
      success: function (data) { 
           console.log(data);
           var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
           if(!$.isEmptyObject(obj))
           {
                $.each(obj, function(index, record) {
                    $('#updateRecord').append('<input type="text" id="myID" value="' + record.firstValue + '"><button type="submit" id="submit" data-theme="b">Update</button>'); 
                });
           }

           $("#update").click(function() {
            var myID= $("#myID").val();
            console.log(myID);
       });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong `$("regionDesc")` selects nothing.

Comment: Oh sorry I updated the code. Thanks its already working now. my selector is wrong :) Thanks again!

Comment: because your update is still missing either the ID (#) or class selectors (.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this `var regionDesc = $("regionDesc").val();`

to this `var regionDesc = $("#regionDesc").val();`

if you are using class attributes then this `var regionDesc = $(".regionDesc").val();`